# Save in an Array or a Json the data of a form when clicking 'Register' button

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am totally new in Xaml and in `C#` (*That's why I do not put forward code*), I'm trying to make an App in `UWP`, and basically what I want, is that when I **click** on the *Register* button, in the generated `click event` an `array` or a `Json` is created with the data that was entered in each of the fields of the form.

If someone explains to me what the process is like and how I can achieve it, I would appreciate it. (Attached Image Form)

[image]

I mean, I want something like this:

```
var objetoJSON = {
  "identification":"valueIdentification",
  "name":"valueName",
  "lastName":"valueLastName",
  etc....
  etc....
};
```

*(They apologize, if the syntax is not C #, because until now I am learning the language, but practically that is what I want)*

Comment: Do you have Model or Model-View for your project?

Comment: No, I only have some xaml controls to assemble the form and a CodeBehind to interact with the events, in this case the 'click'. For now I'm not using models. I only use the `.xaml` and the` .xaml.cs` files

Comment: Ok, If you create a model and view-model for your project, you can bind form input controls into your view-model field/properties. In that case, you can easily serialize your model into a JSON.

Comment: Read this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_data_binding.htm and this: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I will read the documentation. What happens is that I do not understand very well about the models and classes because until now I am learning C #, but I will try. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Ali Bahrami's suggestion, you could use Json.Net to [serialize](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm) a c# object to JSON.

To use Json.Net, you need to install the [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) nuget package for your UWP project.

If you're not familiar with installing the nuget package in visual studio, please see [Quickstart: Install and use a package in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio).

I made a simple code sample for your reference:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="name"></TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="fav"></TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="desc"></TextBox>
    <Button Content="Register" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.Name = name.Text;
        person.Favourite = fav.Text;
        person.Desc = desc.Text;
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person, Formatting.Indented);
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Favourite { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Xie; Thank you!! It worked perfect. Your example was excellent.

Could you explain one last thing? Now that it was possible to generate the Json with the data of the form, how do I do so that for each click on the button 'register', a Json is created whose elements are a different serialize?

Comment: @FernandoChamorro You could create a new `Person` instance and assign the form values to its property like I have done. Then, you could serialize this object.

Comment: Xie, Excuse my ignorance, but I understand little about *POO*, basically the main idea is that for each *click*, the data is stored in a `Json or array` and then I can access that `Json/array` to fill a `ListBox` and see the information of each new record immediately in the listbox.

Comment: @FernandoChamorro Please post a new question and do not ask multiple questions on the same one thread.